# python: command not found even after installing it in GitLab CICD

Tags: gitlab, gcloud, cicd

In GitLab CICD, I am using the Google cloud sdk image `gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:latest` because I have to use `gcloud` in `before_script`. This image doesn't come with python that I also require to run some scripts.

In the `before_script`, I installed python on the Google cloud sdk image using the following command:

```
server_update_dev:
  stage: server_update_dev
  image: gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:latest
  before_script:
    - gcloud config set project abc
    - apt-get -yq update
    - apt-get -yq install python3.10
  script:
    - python test.py
```

But I get the error that `python: command not found`. What mistake I am doing here ? How can I make sure that both `gcloud` and `python` commands are available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mistake is that you assumed `python` command is running `python3`.
To make it possible you can install `python-is-python3` package:

```
apt install python-is-python3
```

and this should work

```
script:
- python test.py
```

or use `python3` explicitly:

```
  script:
  - python3 test.py
```

If you'd have more docker-wise problems you can reproduce it locally:

```
docker run -it gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:latest /bin/bash
```